# Array.prototype.map() did not work correctly

Tags: javascript

```js
/*
Write a function called doubleValues which accepts an array and returns a new array with all the values in the array passed to the function doubled

Examples:
    doubleValues([1,2,3]) // [2,4,6]
    doubleValues([5,1,2,3,10]) // [10,2,4,6,20]

*/

function doubleValues(array){
     return array.map(function(value) {
         return value * 2;
        })
    }

// describe("#doubleValues", function() {
//   it("doubles values in an array", function() {
//     expect(doubleValues([1, 2, 3])).toEqual([2, 4, 6]);
//   });
//   it("works for negative numbers", function() {
//     expect(doubleValues([1, -2, -3])).toEqual([2, -4, -6]);
//   });
// });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.3.0/jasmine.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.3.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.3.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.3.0/boot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foreach-map-filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foreach-map-filter.test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem requires me to Write a function called doubleValues which accepts an array and returns a new array with all the values in the array passed to the function doubled

Examples:
doubleValues([1,2,3]) // [2,4,6]
doubleValues([5,1,2,3,10]) // [10,2,4,6,20]

Why doesn't my function work? Feels like I used the lecturer's code template verbatim. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function doubleValues(array){
     return array.map(function(value) {
         return value * 2;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Your function seems to be working just fine to me. What is the problem you are facing? Please describe input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Interesting, it may be the Jasmine code that was included in the template files I was provided? I will update my code with all my files (JS, HTML, JS.test)

Comment: I've edited this post's code to include my files. I included the Jasmine testing file below the original javascript file I was given (it has all been commented out, so I believe this is okay)? I was also testing it in the browser console that was pulled up in my HTML file

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the test code?

Comment: Yes, I did this and then pulled up the browser console and enterred doubleValues([1,2,3]) in the console.

Comment: okay, just tried it again with Jasmine code uncommented and it worked fine! Not sure what was going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be calling the function, it works. Can you try below code.

```js
function doubleValues(array){
     return array.map(function(value) {
         return value * 2;
        })
    }
    const result=doubleValues([1,2,3])
    console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
var array = [2,5,8,9];
function doubleValues(arr){
     return arr.map((value) => value * 2);
     
}
    
console.log(doubleValues(array));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function doubleValues(array){
     return array.map(x => x * 2);
    }
```

I don't know why you use function(value) in map function.